# How to enter timestamp format from java to oracle database that also has format timestamp?

Tags: java, sql, oracle

I have this table in SQL Oracle database

```
MESSAGES
--------
Name           Null?    Type           
-------------- -------- -------------- 
ID_MESSAGE      NOT NULL NUMBER(38)     
CONTENT          NOT NULL NVARCHAR2(500) 
TIME_STAMP NOT NULL TIMESTAMP(6)
```

And I'm trying to insert a data into this table but I'm having a problem with inserting a timestamp.

I've generated a timestamp in Java and executed the following query:

```java
Timestamp timeStamp = new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());


String query = "INSERT INTO messages(content, time_stamp) VALUES ('"+textAreaSendMessage.getText()+"', "+timeStamp+")";

st.executeQuery(query);
```

And I'm getting this error:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00917: missing comma
```

How to fix this so it inserts timestamp into a database?

Comment: Use parameters with types.  Don't munge query strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that I don't even have to create timestamp in java, just add CURRENT_TIMESTAMP to the place of timestamp into the query where Timestamp should be.

Answer (score 2):

Use `DEFAULT` when defining your table to call a function that captures the current moment. This function will automatically run every time you `INSERT` a new row. Then no need for any Java for this purpose.

If you do want to do something like this in Java, do not use `java.time.Timestamp`. That class was supplanted years ago by the *java.time* classes.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.now( ZoneOffset.UTC ) ;
```

Build your SQL string using `?` placeholders. Do not wrangle with string manipulations as seen in your code sample.

Pass the `OffsetDateTime` object to fill in for the `?` placeholder using a `PreparedStatement` object.

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , odt ) ;
```

[image: Table of date-time types in Java (both modern and legacy) and in standard SQL.]

Comment: Thank you for your recommendation. I will make sure to change all statements in the code to this format as it's more clear in the code and I don't have to search for ' character every single time I am trying to insert something as a String.